# SQL Query for DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a game where controls need to be disabled if the the gameweek's DateTime associated with those controls are 1 hour or longer away from the current time.

I need to create a query in SQL Server 2008 that will bring back all of the gameweekID's that are 1 hour or earlier than the current time.

So an example will be:

GameweekID 1 - FixtureTime 31/03/2013 10:00 (Stored as DateTime in the database)

So if the current time and date is less than 31/03/2013 9:00 it will appear in my query.

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT * FROM Fixture WHERE fixtureDate > '2013/03/31 9:00'
```

But this obviously does not take into consideration the 1 hour before.

I hope this makes sense, was quite confusing to write !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you in the past hour:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT columnList 
FROM fixture
WHERE fixtureDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND NOW()
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT columnList
FROM fixture
WHERE fixtureDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

This will give you anything greater than 1 hour:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT columnList 
FROM fixture
WHERE fixtureDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT columnList
FROM fixture
WHERE fixtureDate < DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())
```

*Reference*

- [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This didn't work. I get an error saying Date_Sub and Now are not recognized functions

Comment: Well what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I thought I put that in the post, I will edit it. SQL Server

Comment: @PolishPrince +1, nice; you might add this for a "pure ANSI" option: `where fixtureDate < (current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1' HOUR)`

Comment: @PolishPrince All databases I work on support `current_date` and `current_timestamp` as constants (particularly Teradata, Oracle, and SQL Server); they are ANSI standards and make system calls to get the current date and timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you would use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM Fixture WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, fixtureDate, GetDate()) >= 1
```